# Laravel Eloquent COUNT(*) NO Result GroupBy()

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have query on laravel

```
$types=Types::selectRaw('COUNT(property_types.id) as total, property_types.types, property_types.id')

               ->join('properties', 'property_types.id', '=', 
                      'properties.property_type')
               ->where('property_purpose', '"Sale"')
               ->groupBy('property_types.id','property_types.id','property_types.types')
               ->get();
```

And  I dont have any result

```
Collection {#383 ▼
```

#items: []

I change ->get() by ->toSql(); And I have laravel query

```
select COUNT(property_types.id) as total, property_types.types, property_types.id 
from `property_types` 
inner join `properties` on `property_types`.`id` = `properties`.`property_type`
where `property_purpose` = ? 
group by `property_types`.`id`, `property_types`.`id`, `property_types`.`types`
```

Change ? by variable "Sale"  copy and paste on PhpMyadmin and  I got te result that I want

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUPZo.png)

I dont know what wrong on Laravel Eloquent!

Answer (score 0):

That work for me

$types=Types::selectRaw('COUNT(property_types.id) as total, property_types.types, property_types.id')

```
           ->join('properties', 'property_types.id', '=', 
                  'properties.property_type')
           ->where('property_purpose', 'Sale')
           ->groupBy('property_types.id','property_types.id','property_types.types')
           ->get();
```